# Simple application of Gauss-Bonnet theorem

Tags: differential-geometry

Just for verification, I take the following to be the local Gauss Bonnet Theorem:

$\int_{R}K dA + \int_{\partial{R}} K_gds = 2\pi \chi(R) $

Where $\chi(R)$ is the Euler characteristic of the region R.

The question asks me to deduce that there are no simple smoothly closed 
geodesics on $ S = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \vert z = x^2 - y^2\} $

To do this, I've calculated the Gaussian curvature to be everywhere negative, so I presume I'm supposed to reason that if there were such a geodesic then considering the region it encloses to be R:

$$\int_{\partial{R}} K_gds = 0$$

and then derive some kind of contradiction based on the facts that:

$$\int_{R}K dA < 0$$  and,    $$  2\pi \chi(R)> 0$$

However, I'm not quite sure how to justify the 2nd inequality. It seems sort of obvious, since I'd imagine the  region R to be homotopy equivalent to a closed disc with Euler characteristic 1 but I'm not sure about this.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can take this for granted - a simple curve on ${\mathbb R}^2$ (your surface is diffeomorphic to ${\mathbb r}^2$) bounds a domain that is homeomorphic to a disc. For a proof see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_problem   In your case the curve is smooth and the proof is not hard.

Comment: Note that the paraboloid is diffeomorphic to the plane.